# chmod a file inside a docker container

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, docker, permissions, chmod

I'm running a Roots Bedrock WordPress installation inside a Docker container that runs inside a single docker container AWS Elastic Beanstalk. This container builds using the following DockerFile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

VOLUME ["/var/www/html"]

# Install locales
RUN apt update && apt install -y locales
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8

ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

# Get latest version of software-properties-common first
RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y && apt install -y software-properties-common

# Pre-add php7 repo
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php \
    && apt update

# Basic Requirements
RUN apt update \
    && apt install -y nginx curl unzip git supervisor wget python-pip sqlite3

# PHP Requirements
RUN apt update \
    && apt install -y php7.1 php7.1-fpm php7.1-cli php7.1-mcrypt php7.1-gd php7.1-mysql \
    php7.1-imap php-memcached php7.1-mbstring php7.1-xml php7.1-curl \
    php7.1-sqlite3

# Wordpress Requirements
RUN apt update \
    && apt install -y libnuma-dev php7.1-intl php-pear php7.1-imagick \
    php7.1-ps php7.1-pspell php7.1-recode php7.1-sqlite php7.1-tidy php7.1-xmlrpc php7.1-xsl

# Install Composer
RUN php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer

# Install WP-CLI
RUN curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar \
    && chmod +x wp-cli.phar \
    && mv wp-cli.phar /usr/local/bin/wp

# Misc. Cleanup
RUN mkdir /run/php \
    && apt remove -y --purge software-properties-common \
    && apt -y autoremove \
    && apt clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* \
    && echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
    && ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log

COPY config/nginx/ /etc/nginx/
COPY config/php-fpm.conf /etc/php/7.1/fpm/php-fpm.conf

COPY src/ /var/www/html/

EXPOSE 80

COPY config/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

I need to make the uploads folder of WordPress writable. But after several attempts I cannot get it to chmod 775. It maintains 755.

What I tried inside the DockerFile after `COPY src/ /var/www/html/`

```
RUN chown -R root:www-data /var/www/html/web/app/uploads
RUN chmod 775 /var/www/html/web/app/uploads
```

The project builds using AWS CodeBuild. This runs `composer install`, `npm install`, `bower install` and `gulp`. After this build the source code will be deployed on EBS and the DockerFile will build.

Comment: did you get to the bottom of it?

Comment: Hi Arek,

In the end we used a NFS and mounted a volume to that. We changed permissions there. Bottom line: Changing folder permissions on the host also affects the folder permissions in the container.